# HTML5 canvas drawing from video source

Tags: javascript, performance, html5, canvas

I have the following code, which draws a overlay image onto video for each frame:

```
video.addEventListener( 'play', function() {

    var $this = this; // cache

    (function drawCurrentFrameToCanvas() {
        if ( ! $this.paused && ! $this.ended ) {
            drawImage();
            requestAnimationFrame( drawCurrentFrameToCanvas ); // rAF is supported by most browsers in nowdays.
        }
    })();

}, 0);

function drawImage() {

    var points = getTrackingPoints();

    if( ! points ) return;  

    var lh = points.pt4.y - points.pt2.y; 
    var lw = points.pt2.x - points.pt1.x; 
    var pw = ( lw < points.pt4.x - points.pt3.x ) ? points.pt4.x - points.pt3.x : lw; /* get longest left/right side */
    var ph = ( lh < points.pt3.y - points.pt1.y ) ? points.pt3.y - points.pt1.y : lh; /* get longest top/bottom side */
    var dx = points.pt2.x - points.pt1.x;
    var dy = points.pt2.y - points.pt1.y;
    var radianAngle = (Math.atan2(dy,dx)+Math.PI*2) % (Math.PI*2);

    ctx.clearRect( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height ); 

    dot( points.pt1.x, points.pt1.y );
    dot( points.pt2.x, points.pt2.y );
    dot( points.pt3.x, points.pt3.y );
    dot( points.pt4.x, points.pt4.y );

    ctx.save();

    ctx.translate( points.pt1.x, points.pt1.y );
    ctx.rotate( radianAngle );
    ctx.translate( -points.pt1.x, -points.pt1.y );

    // ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;

    if( typeof template !== 'undefined' ) {
        ctx.drawImage(template, points.pt1.x, points.pt1.y, pw, ph);
    }

    ctx.restore();

}
```

Where template used here is standard `HTMLImageElement`:

```
ctx.drawImage(template, points.pt1.x, points.pt1.y, pw, ph);
```

Is there a way to optimize it, to work faster?